# On\Off WLAN on Win CE - how?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

i try OpenNETCF for Open and close Wlan on win ce - and **no Success !!**

i try this:

```
  [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SetDevicePower(string pvDevice, int dwDeviceFlags, DevicePowerState DeviceState);

        private enum DevicePowerState : int
        {
            Unspecified = -1,
            D0 = 0, // Full On: full power, full functionality 
            D1, // Low Power On: fully functional at low power/performance 
            D2, // Standby: partially powered with automatic wake 
            D3, // Sleep: partially powered with device initiated wake 
            D4, // Off: unpowered 
        }

        private const int POWER_NAME = 0x00000001;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string driver = FindDriverKey();
            SetDevicePower(driver, POWER_NAME, DevicePowerState.D0);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string driver = FindDriverKey();
            SetDevicePower(driver, POWER_NAME, DevicePowerState.D4);
        }

        private static string FindDriverKey()
        {
            string ret = string.Empty;
            string WiFiDriverClass = "{98C5250D-C29A-4985-AE5F-AFE5367E5006}";
            foreach (string tmp in Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Power\\State", false).GetValueNames())
            {
                if (tmp.Contains(WiFiDriverClass))
                {
                    ret = tmp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

and still **no Success !!**

how to open and close WIFI on win ce ?  (no windows-mobile)

is it possible at all using C# code ?

thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure you driver key GUID is correct? Have you checked in the registry to see if this refers to the WLAN adapter?

Comment: i dont know what to check, can i get any help ?

Comment: Does FindDriverKey() succeed or does it return an empty string? If it fails, then take a look a that location in the registry with remote registry editor. The OEM may have assigned a non-default power class to the wifi radio.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API that may or may not be included in your CE build, in ossvcs.dll.  You can use `GetWirelessDevices()` and `ChangeRadioState()` to turn radios on/off.  You'll need to pinvoke ossvcs.dll

Pinvoke example [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=413159)

Comment: I suspect this will fail if the SDF is failing (since that's what the SDF is using to change state).

Comment: I wondered if that might be the case.  Hear hear Chris then; go and talk to the OEM.

Comment: +1 for adding the API info anyway.  Furture readers might find it handy.

Answer (score 1):

Support for this greatly depends on the WiFi adapter, driver and the OS image your OEM provided.  It seems you've tried the obvious stuff (SetDevicePower, CHangeRadioStatre, etc) so assuming you did this all correctly (I've not verified the driver class GUIKLD you used), then the poower for the radio could very well not be exposed, or may only be exposed via a proprietary API.  Is the radio a plug-in type, or is it built into the hardware?  What type of hardware is this?  Have you checked with the OEM?  Can you turn it off via the Control Panel (that would at least indicate if you do or don't have an API). It's quite possible that the radio is hard-wired for power or it's coming from something like a CPLD.  Only the device OEM would really know.